# How to create a Dataset from a csv which doesn't have a header and has more than 150 columns using scala spark

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I've a csv which I need to read as Dataset. The csv is having 140 columns and it doesn't have a header.
I created a schema with `StructType(Seq(StructFiled(...), Seq(StructFiled(...), ...))` and the code to read that is as follows:-

```
object dataParser {
def getData(inputPath: String, delimeter: String)(implicit spark: SparkSession): Dataset[MyCaseClass] = {
  val parsedData: Dataset[MyCaseClass] = spark.read
                                         .option("header", "false")
                                         .option("delimeter", "delimeter")
                                         .option("inferSchema", "true")
                                         .schema(mySchema)
                                         .load(inputPath)
                                         .as[MyCaseClass]
  parsedData
}
}
```

And the case class I created is like:-

```
case class MycaseClass(
    mycaseClass1: MyCaseClass1,
    mycaseClass2: MyCaseClass2,
    mycaseClass3: MyCaseClass3,
    mycaseClass4: MyCaseClass4,
    mycaseClass5: MyCaseClass5,
    mycaseClass6: MyCaseClass6,
    mycaseClass7: MyCaseClass7,
)

MyCaseClass1(
 first 20 columns of csv: it's datatypes
)

MyCaseClass2(
 next 20 columns of csv: it's datatypes
)
```

and so on.

But when I'm trying to compile it, it gives me an error as below:-

```
Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
[error]                                                 .as[myCaseClass]
```

I'm calling this from my Scala App as :-

````
object MyTestApp{
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
  implicit val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
 run(args)
}

def run(args: Array[String])(implicit spark: SparkSession): Unit = {
val inputPath = args.get("inputData")
val delimeter = Constants.delimeter
 val myData = Dataparser.getData(inputPath, delimeter)
}
}
```
I'm not very sure about the approach also as I'm new to Dataset.
I saw multiple answers around this issue but they were mainly for very small no of columns which can be contained within the scope of a single case class and that too with header which makes this little simpler.
Any help would be really appreciated.
````

Comment: What are the data types in your case class?

Comment: Since this has 140 columns, it has all datatypes, majorly String, Integer and Date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the viewers. Actually I found the issue. Posting the answer here so that other's who come across any such issue, will be able to get rid of this issue.

I needed to import the spark.implicits._ here

```
object dataParser {
def getData(inputPath: String, delimeter: String)(implicit spark: SparkSession): Dataset[MyCaseClass] = {
**import spark.implicits._**
  val parsedData: Dataset[MyCaseClass] = spark.read
                                         .option("header", "false")
                                         .option("delimeter", "delimeter")
                                         .option("inferSchema", "true")
                                         .schema(mySchema)
                                         .load(inputPath)
                                         .as[MyCaseClass]
  parsedData
}
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that was in the App, but we need that even in the parser.

Comment: Umm, looks like there are more issues with this code. Will need a little help in here. The schema is heavy having approx 150 columns but the case class has a limitation of 23. So, how do we provide the as part to the dataset while reading?

Comment: You can right, case class can't handle so many columns :( But there is a trick I know. I will post answer after sometime.